# Why is Apache redirecting me when I access using ip address?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have this default `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this one I created, `my.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLEngine on
        ...
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I try `example.com` on the browser, I get redirected to `https://example.com/`, which is fine.

But if I try `123.45.67.89` I also get redirected to `https://example.com/`.

Since both virtual servers (*:80) are a match for `123.45.67.89`, and no `ServerName` is a match for `123.45.67.89`, I expected Apache 2.4 to select the one in `000-default.conf`. But it is not. Why?

My reference is [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost):

> If multiple virtual hosts contain the best matching IP address and
>   port, the server selects from these virtual hosts the best match based
>   on the requested hostname. If no matching name-based virtual host is
>   found, then the first listed virtual host that matched the IP address
>   will be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default [Name-Based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) is missing the [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername).

> If you omit the `ServerName` directive from any name-based virtual host,
>   the server will default to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
>   derived from the system hostname. This implicitly set server name can
>   lead to counter-intuitive virtual host matching and is discouraged.

It might be that the derived FQDN is matching the hostname in the second virtual host, causing unintuitive problems in [Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html).

The same is also suggested and explained in [Issues Regarding DNS and Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dns-caveats.html):

> In order for the server to function properly, it absolutely needs to
>   have two pieces of information about each virtual host: the `ServerName`
>   and at least one IP address that the server will bind and respond to.
>
> ```
> # This is a misconfiguration example, do not use on your server
> <VirtualHost 192.0.2.1>
>   ServerAdmin webgirl@example.dom
>   DocumentRoot "/www/example"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> This time httpd needs to use reverse DNS to find the `ServerName` for
>   this virtualhost. If that reverse lookup fails then it will partially
>   disable the virtualhost. If the virtual host is name-based then it
>   will effectively be totally disabled.

**Add something to the `ServerName`. Anything.** Your first `<VirtualHost>` will still be the default unless there's another match. It can even be the IP address. Just don't leave it unspecified. Use e.g.

- `ServerName 198.51.100.10` (with your server's IP) or
- `ServerName default-catch-all.example.org`

Comment: I will try. But before that, let's imagine this derived FQDN is matching the hostname in the second virtual host. Now we have two `*:80` with `ServerName example.com`. I'm accessing it by IP on port 80, so both are initially matches, but then none of them are `ServerName` matches. In this case it should choose the first listed, which is `000-default`. But no, it is choosing the one in `my.conf`.

Comment: [Here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dns-caveats.html#tips), I found this: _This time (without ServerName) httpd needs to use reverse DNS to find the ServerName for this virtualhost. If that reverse lookup fails then it will partially disable the virtualhost. If the virtual host is name-based then it will effectively be totally disabled_. Maybe the default virtual host is being ignored.

Comment: Yes, that was the other condition. I just couldn't find the _reverse DNS_ fallback explained anywhere at the moment. The suggestion is still exactly the same, I just modified my answer to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

The first listed host depends on the order the configuration is loaded.  Different distributions have different mechanisms for loading the files.

On Ubuntu, sites should be defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. These are enabled by creating a link in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.  The enabled sites are loaded in canonical order from that directory. Files in `sites-available` that are not linked to `sites-enabled` are not loaded.

The configuration loads files from `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and `etc/apache2/conf-enabled` are loaded prior to loading sites from `sites-enabled`.

If you enable the info module, you should be able to review the configuration by navigating to `https://www.example.com/server-info`.  Check the order of the virtual hosts on this page.

It is also possible to place Redirects in `.htaccess` file located in the document directory.  It is also possible to place redirection directives inside containers other than a `Virtualhost` container.

You may want to verify which redirections are occurring by dumping the server headers.  I use a command like `wget -qSO /dev/null http://192.0.2.22`.  This will show the headers from each redirection.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16. Both conf are in sites-available and linked in sites-enabled.

Comment: @Gustavo What order are they in sites-enabled?

Comment: When I `ls -la`, `000-default.conf` is the first in the list.

Comment: @Gustavo I've updated my response.You may also want to investigate how to log redirections.

Comment: `server-info` showed the order I expected. The redirection:
`wget -qSO /dev/null http://123.45.67.89
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 31 May 2017 19:19:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://example.com/
Content-Length: 308
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: @Gustavo See https://serverfault.com/questions/10796/apache-where-to-examine-the-redirection-logs for details on logging rewrites.  Try temporarily modifying the rewrite in the site file, or even disabling it to test that that is the the redirect that is invoked.